# NodeJs, how to access a variable inside a module

Tags: node.js

I create a boolean variable at outside the module and I try to change the variable at inside the module but when I call the variable at outside the module, it returns the old value, not the one in the module.

```js
var namecontroll = false;
dbo.collection('users').findOne({name: data.name}, (ferr, fres) => {
    if (ferr) throw ferr
    if (fres) {
        var namecontroll = false;
        io.emit('signup feedback',"This username was taken by another user.");
    }
    else {
        var namecontroll = true;
    }
    db.close;
})
```

When I control the value in the module by console.log, it can return 'true'. But when I control out the module, even when the condition is provided, it returns 'false'. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Well it looks like asynchronous code with a callback.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you "control out the module"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all take into consideration that your code is asynchronous and you can just check the variable value before function execution is done. As for the structure of it you are re-declaring the `namecontroll` variable with `var` keyword inside your function, that means that you are creating new variable inside the function instead of changing it value. Try to do something like this:

```
var namecontroll = false;
dbo.collection('users').findOne({name: data.name}, (ferr, fres) => {
    if (ferr) throw ferr
    if (fres) {
        namecontroll = false;
        io.emit('signup feedback',"This username was taken by another user.");
    }
    else {
        namecontroll = true;
    }
    db.close;
})
```